# Sql sort query to sort parents and childrens of the same model

Tags: sql, django, django-orm

I have a `Comment` model which has relationship to itself meaning each comment has a `comment_parent_id`. I want to sort comments so first parent comment comes first then all of its children, then next comment, after that next comment children, etc. 

Is it a way to do it in a single sql query? I'm using Django so both Django ORM or raw queries works for me.

Comment: I think you can attach `.order_by("comment_parent_id")` at the end of your query to accomplish this.

Comment: @MattCremeens No that won't do it. doing it will show all comments with commnet_parent_id = null first and that is not what i want

Comment: Then how about `.exclude(comment_parent_id=null).order_by("comment_parent_id")`

Comment: which database do you use?

Comment: @MattCremeens I don't want to exclude parent comments, I want one parent comment then its children then another parent comment

Comment: @latsha i'm using mysql

Comment: This should just exclude the ones where the parent id is null, which is what I thought you wanted.

Comment: I think it's very possible to show parent comments id next to children comments id in one row but I'm not sure about showing it by the way you want

Comment: One approach: if you added a field called `thread_id` which is set for both parent and child when somebody replies to a comment (and subsequent replies are set to the same id), then you can do it with `.order_by('thread_id', 'parent_comment_id')` Or you could then replace 'parent_comment_id' with a Boolean 'is_parent' for `.order_by('thread_id', 'is_parent')`